# help me understand "off" when it comes to phrasal verb

Tags: usage

I have seen those words on the internet

Based off....

Better off...

I thought "off" meaning get away from something

but why does "off" mean quite not the way I thought

Comment: based off is in fact not a legitimate english phrase.  It comes from the phrase based on

Comment: I think you mean "based on".' My advice to you is to drop the term 'phrasal verb'. It's a misnomer. It's not the whole expression "based on" that is a verb, but just the word "based".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The construction *based off* is a non-standard variation of the construction *based on*, and you should use *based on* instead.

These are phrasal verbs. For the majority of phrasal verbs, their meaning can be deduced by analyzing the meanings of the separate components, but often it cannot, particularly for the most common ones. This is true for all phrasal verbs, not just the ones containing *off*, but also those containing *in*, *on*, and so forth.

You will just have to learn the meanings of these common phrasal verbs.

Similarly, the meanings of the constructions *better off* and *worse off* aren't easily deduced from their components. But these two phrases aren't part of a whole class of constructions where you have to learn the meaning of each one, like phrasal verbs are. Usually, when it's not part of a phrasal verb, *off* means "away from something" or "separated from something" (as it does in many phrasal verbs).